# Kafka Topic creation upon specific broker

Tags: apache-kafka

Regarding *Kafka* [topic creation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_kafka-component-guide/content/ch_create-kafka-topic.html). I have an understanding that *Kafka* cluster can have several brokers/nodes/servers. Each broker can have one or more topics configured. A topic created could be in one or more brokers depending on partitions provided during topic creation. Is there any way how one can tell in which broker/s should a topic and it's partitions be created?

Regards, 
Lokesh

Answer (score 3):

When creating the topic, you can either just specify the number of partitions and replicas and let Kafka distribute them. Or you can directly specify the assignment - which partition and replica goes where.

If you are using the `kafka-topics.sh` script which is part of kafka, you can use the option `--replica-assignment` for it. For example:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --replica-assignment 0:1:2,0:1:2,0:1:2
```

If the topic already exists, you can use the `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool to change the assignment.

This might contain some more details about is: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-2.2CreateTopics